# How can I boot mysql?

Tags: mysql, terminal

After I install mysql in my terminal like this

```
brew install mysql
```

I try to open it like this

```
mysql -uroot
```

but it appear an error:ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
What should I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting mysql server with this command: **mysql.server start**

and if this not help try: **brew services start mysql**